# Can I use a "Gutschein" from Deutsche Bahn more than once?

Tags: trains, germany, compensation, deutsche-bahn

I cancelled a trip with Deutsche Bahn and they gave me a "Gutschein" (German word for coupon or voucher) with the value of the trip. If I use this Gutschein to buy something of less value, can I use the rest of the Gutschein again?

In the [website](https://www.bahn.de/p/view/service/buchung/gutschein/stornogutschein.shtml), they say

> Wenn Sie Gutschein und eCoupon kombinieren und der Wert der Gutscheine insgesamt den Ticketpreis übersteigt, können wir Ihnen für den Restbetrag leider keinen Restwert-Gutschein ausstellen.
>
> Rough translation: If you combine a Gutschein and an eCoupon, and the total value of the vouchers exceeds the ticket price, we will unfortunately not be able to issue you a "residual value voucher" (Restwert-Gutschein) for the remaining amount.

But it is not clear to me if I can get a "Restwert-Gutschein" when I just use a Gutschein and not a Gutschein together with an eCoupon.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Travel:SE! Would you be willing to add an English translation of that German paragraph? I went to the website myself and set it to English, but wasn't able to find the exact part of the site! If it's too much trouble, that's no problem! Thanks!

Comment: I did a rough translation

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The important part is on the same page, just above.

> Sollte Ihr Gutscheinwert höher sein als Ihr Buchungsbetrag, erhalten Sie einen Restwertgutschein.

So, yes, you get a new *Gutschein* with the remaining value.

Only if you used both a *Gutschein* **and** and *eCoupon*, they won't give you a *Gutschein* with the remaining value. The combined use of those *eCoupons* with *any other bonus* is tricky.

Comment: I believe that I read somewhere that this "problem" can be circumvented with the following steps: (1) Buy a "flexible price" ticket for the far future for  the price of the ticket you want minus the eCoupon without using the eCoupon or a little bit more.. You will receive a "Restwertgutschein". (2) Cancel the ticket and receive a new "Gutschein" for the value of the ticket just cancelled, (3) Buy the ticket you want with the new "Gutschein" of the right value and the eCoupon. (4) You now have the ticket you want plus the "Restwertgutschein" from step 1.